# JavaScript: how to call JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

How to call getDate function using dateTime variable

```
var dateTime = function(){
    var dateSrv = {};
    dateSrv.prototype.getDate = function(){
        return new Date().toDateString();
    };
    dateSrv.prototype.getTime = function(){
        return new Date().toTimeString();
    };

    return dateSrv;
};
console.log(dateTime.getDate());
```

Comment: i get error when try to call inner getDate function

Answer (score 4):

This is what you need:

```
var dateTime = function(){
    var dateSrv = {};
    dateSrv.getDate = function(){
        return new Date().toDateString();
    };

    dateSrv.getTime = function(){
        return new Date().toTimeString();
    };

    return dateSrv;
};

console.log(dateTime().getDate());
```

1. In this case you don't need to define methods inside the object `prototype`, just add the functions to the object.
2. Also note that `dateTime` is a function so it must be called with `()` to get what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

you take  two mistake :

**1**

```
 var dateSrv = {};
    dateSrv.prototype.getDate = function(){
        return new Date().toDateString();
    };
```

dateSrv is a object , it have not prototype which is inherit by Function(not function),
just write this :

```
dateSrv.getDate = function (){...}
```

**2**

```
 console.log(dateTime.getDate());
```

dateTime is not a object. it's a funcation 
you can fix it to :
console.log(dateTime().getDate());
but i guess this is you want :

```
var dateTime = function () {
    var dateSrv = {};
    dateSrv.getDate = function () {
        return new Date().toDateString();
    };
    dateSrv.getTime = function () {
        return new Date().toTimeString();
    };

    return dateSrv;
}();
```

() means the fun will be excute immediate,so dateTime is the return value ----a object with two prototype.

Ps: english is not my mother tongue , hope you can understand what i say o(∩_∩)o

Comment: Ha~~  i took over 15 min to  write this simple answer in English,maybe i should improve my writing ability  first